# URL not finding state ( ui.router and angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following states:

```
$stateProvider.
            state('candidates', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/candidates',
                templateUrl: '/Scripts/App/js/Views/candidates/candidates.html',
                controller: 'candidatesTableController'
            }).                
            state('candidates.item', {
                url: '/{item:[0-9]{1,4}}',
                templateUrl: '/Scripts/App/js/Views/candidates/candidate.html',
                controller: 'candidatesDetailController'
            }).
            state('candidates.item.details', {
                url: '/details',
                templateUrl: '/Scripts/App/js/Views/candidates/partials/generalDetails.html',
                controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
                            $scope.item= $stateParams.item;
               }
            }).
            state('candidates.item.edit', {
                url: '/details/edit',
                templateUrl: '/Scripts/App/js/Views/candidates/partials/form.html',
                controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
                            $scope.item = $stateParams.item;
                }
            }).state('candidates.item.photo', {
                url: '/details/photo',
                templateUrl: '/Scripts/App/js/Views/candidates/partials/updatePhotoID.html',
                controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
                            $scope.item = $stateParams.item;
                }
            });
```

Here my urlRouterProvider:

```
$urlRouterProvider
            .when('/candidates/:item', '/candidates/:item/details')
            .otherwise("/");
```

When I use ui-sref everything work fine but when i using the actual url, it never can find the following url:

"/#/candidates/4/details"

it redirect to the root ("/#/")

I can't figure out why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created a plunkr with your routes defined here: 
http://run.plnkr.co/Sn3s7ooM6MOSxQnB/#/candidates/4/details

Code visible here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/wArFenIZ7j3WczUhtJO6

Notice that the first link in this answer takes you right to the details page for a candidate item.  Maybe you can figure out from my simplified code what it is that you need to change to achieve the same behavior.

Also, I noticed that your redirect doesn't work (the second nav item in my plunker allows you to go to this state without a redirect; try clicking it yourself):

`.when('/candidates/:item', '/candidates/:item/details')`

This redirect *will* work if you set the `candidates.item` state to be `abstract`.  Maybe this is what you want.

See this in action here: http://plnkr.co/edit/y9LI0OKGMStVnMY2NX5q

Code visible here: http://plnkr.co/edit/y9LI0OKGMStVnMY2NX5q

I hope that helps